# Update people or group field of sharepoint list C# code

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, splistitem

I have a console app, it updates people or group field of sharepoint list. If the item["Approver"] value is a user value this app works fine. If the item["Approver"] value is a sharepoint group this will fail.
I expect this app should work if the item["Approver"] value is both user or group. Can someone suggest the code part to make me success?

```
static  SPWeb _web;
        static SPSite _site;
        static SPList myList;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string usercontrolvalue = "test";
            _site = new SPSite("URL");
            _web = _site.OpenWeb();
            _web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            myList = _web.Lists["MYList"];
            SPListItem item = myList.Items.Add();
            SPFieldUserValueCollection usercollection = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
            string[] userarray = usercontrolvalue.Split(',');
            for (int i = 0; i < userarray.Length; i++)
            {
                SPFieldUserValue usertoadd = ConvertLoginName(userarray[i]);
                usercollection.Add(usertoadd);
            }
            item["Approver"] = usercollection;
            item.Update();
        }


        public static SPFieldUserValue ConvertLoginName(string userid)
        {
            SPUser requireduser = _web.EnsureUser(userid);
            SPFieldUserValue uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(_web, requireduser.ID, requireduser.LoginName);
            return uservalue; 
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error while updating?

Comment: Invalid user "test", while test is a SharePoint group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the **ConvertLoginName** method to:

```
public static SPFieldUserValue ConvertLoginName(string userid)
{
    // Try to get the SPUser value if userid is a user or AD group that has been imported into SharePoint by the UPS.
    try {
        SPUser requireduser = _web.EnsureUser(userid);
        SPFieldUserValue uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(_web, requireduser.ID, requireduser.LoginName);
        return uservalue;
    } catch {}

    // Try to get the SPGroup value if userid is a SharePoint group in the current site collection.
    try {
        SPGroup requiredgroup = _web.SiteGroups[userid];
        SPFieldUserValue uservalue = new SPFieldUserValue(_web, requiredgroup.ID, requiredgroup.LoginName);
        return uservalue;
    } catch { }

    // Return null if the userid cannot be resolved to a SharePoint user or group.
    return null;
}
```

Also, you may want to change the body of the **for loop** to check if the **ConvertLoginName** method returns null.

Remarks:

- I have not tested the code, but it is similar to the code I wrote in a PowerShell script, so it should work.
- The new **ConvertLoginName** method assumes that the userid string has the following form for SharePoint users: **domain\username** or **email address**; the string for SharePoint group needs to be the name of the group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use following extension methods to update the user/group field:

**Single User/Group**

```
public static void SetUserValue(this SPListItem item, string columnName, int userId)
{
    SPWeb web = item.Web;
    item[columnName] = new SPFieldUserValue(web, userId.ToString());
}
```

**Multiple User/Group**

```
public static void SetUserValueCollection(this SPListItem item, string columnName, int[] userIds)
{
    SPWeb web = item.Web;
    var value = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();
    value.AddRange(userIds.Select(i => new SPFieldUserValue(web, i.ToString())));
    item[columnName] = value;
}

public static void SetUserToValueCollection(this SPListItem item, string columnName, int userId)
{
    SPWeb web = item.Web;
    SPFieldUserValueCollection value = (item[columnName] != null) 
        ? value = item[columnName] as SPFieldUserValueCollection 
        : value = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

    value.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(web, userId.ToString()));
    item[columnName] = value;
}
```

You can find extension methods for `SPListItem` at following link:
http://customsp.blogspot.com/2014/10/SPListItem-Extension-Methods-to-get-and-set-field-values.html